# Map on Map<'a, int>

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following type :

```
type MultiSet<'a when 'a: comparison> = MSet of Map<'a, int>
```

and I now want to declare af map function for this type with the signature :

```
('a -> 'b) -> Multiset<'a> -> Multiset<'b> when 'a : comparison and 'b : comparison
```

I have tried :

```
let map m ms =
    match ms with
    | MSet s -> MSet ( Map.map (fun key value -> m key) s )
```

But that it has the signature :

```
('a -> int) -> Multiset<'a> -> Multiset<'a> when 'a : comparison
```

What is wrong with my implementation when I want the first mentioned function signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map.map` maps *values*, not keys. And with good reason: it can't just go and plug the mapped keys instead of the original ones - they might not fit. Heck, they might not even be unique for all `Map.map` knows!

If you want to construct a map with different keys, you'll have to take it apart as a sequence, convert it, then construct another `Map` from it:

```
let map m (MSet s) =
  MSet ( Map.ofSeq <| seq { for KeyValue (key, value) in s -> m key, value } )
```

This implementation has your required signature.

(also, notice how you don't have to do `match`, you can include the pattern right in parameter declaration)

**Beware** that this implementation does nothing for validating the new keys: for example, if they turn out to be non-unique, some counts will be lost. I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Note that it may also be worth considering what to do when multiple old keys map to the same new key (should the counts be added together, or an error raised, or an arbitrary value be kept?)

Comment: This is a good point. But I didn't want to overload the answer, just solved the immediate problem.