# Subtract two Maps of Map<'a, int>

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following type:

```
type Multiset<'a when 'a: comparison> = MSet of Map<'a, int>
```

I want to declare a function for this type that subtracts two MSets.

Let's say I have the following two Multisets:

```
let f = MSet (Map.ofList [("a",1);("b",2);("c",1)])
let g = MSet (Map.ofList [("a",1);("b",3);("c",1)])
```

I have now tried to create this subtract function which takes two Multisets.

```
let subtract fms sms =
             match fms with 
             | MSet fs -> match sms with 
                          | MSet ss -> 
                                      let toList ms = Map.fold (fun keys key value -> keys @ [for i = 1 to value do yield key] ) [] ms 
                                      let fromList l = match l with 
                                                       | [] -> MSet(Map.ofList [])
                                                       | x::xs -> MSet(Map.ofList (x::xs |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList))
                        let sfList = toList fs
                        let ssList = toList ss
                        fromList (List.filter (fun n -> not (List.contains n sfList)) ssList)
```

If I run :

```
subtract f g
```

It returns :

```
MSet (map [])
```

Which is not what I wanted. g contains one more b than f, so I would want it to return:

```
MSet(map [("b", 1)])
```

My implementation doesn't account for multiple occurrences of the same key. I am not quite sure how I can fix this, so I get the wanted functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you just have your arguments reversed, that's all. Try `subtract g f`.

That said, your solution seems way more complicated than it needs to be. How about just updating the values in the first map by subtracting the counts in the second, then removing non-positive counts?

```
let sub (MSet a) (MSet b) =
    let bCount key = match Map.tryFind key b with | Some c -> c | None -> 0
    let positiveCounts, _ = 
        a 
        |> Map.map (fun key value -> value - (bCount key))
        |> Map.partition (fun _ value -> value > 0)
    MSet positiveCounts
```

Also, the nested match in your implementation doesn't need to be there. If you wanted to match on both arguments, you can just do:

```
match fms, sms with
| MSet fs, MSet ss -> ...
```

But even *that* is an overkill - you can just include the pattern in parameter declarations, like in my implementation above.

As for duplicate keys - in this case, there is no reason to worry: neither of the arguments can have duplicate keys (because they're both `Map`s), and the algorithm will never produce any.

Comment: I learn so much from these great answers, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue, also evident in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162927/map-on-mapa-int), seems to be the unification of identical keys. This requires an equality constraint and can be easily effected by the high-level function `Seq.groupBy`. Since comparison isn't strictly necessary, I propose using a dictionary, but the approach would work also with maps.

Given a type

```
type MultiSet<'T> = MultiSet of System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<'T, int>
```

and a helper which maps the keys, sums their values and validates the result;

```
let internal mapSum f = 
    Seq.groupBy (fun (KeyValue(k, _)) -> f k)
    >> Seq.map (fun (k, kvs) -> k, Seq.sumBy (fun (KeyValue(_, v)) -> v) kvs)
    >> Seq.filter (fun (_, v) -> v > 0)
    >> dict
    >> MultiSet
```

your operations become:

```
let map f (MultiSet s) =
    mapSum f s

let add (MultiSet fms) (MultiSet sms) =
    Seq.append fms sms
    |> mapSum id

let subtract (MultiSet fms) (MultiSet sms) =
    Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(k, v)) ->
        System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(k, -v)) sms
    |> Seq.append fms
    |> mapSum id

let f = MultiSet(dict["a", 1; "b", 2; "c", 1])
let g = MultiSet(dict["a", 1; "b", 3; "c", 1])

subtract f g
// val it : MultiSet<string> = MultiSet (seq [])
subtract g f
// val it : MultiSet<string> = MultiSet (seq [[b, 1] {Key = "b";
//                                                    Value = 1;}])
```

Comment: For this operation, there is no possibility of duplicate keys appearing.